# Proportional center a div keeping scaling option

Tags: css

I'm trying this 404 error page:

[Error page](http://media.dday.it/roby/404/)

How can I keep the image with the right proportion centered to the screen and resizing?
I try to add margins but the background image expand to the entire page!

[Here is the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LAKXK/2/)

Code

```
<div id="tv">
    <div id="content"> <a href="http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/" id="logo"><img src="http://media.dday.it/roby/404/404_files/images/ddaylog.png" alt="DDay Logo"/></a> 
            <h1 class="scale1" style="font-size: 115.2px;">404</h1>

            <h2 class="scale2" style="font-size: 38.4px;"><span>Non c'è nulla</span> su questa frequenza</h2>

        <p class="scale3" style="font-size: 50px;">Cambia canale e torna su <a href="http://www.dday.it/">DDay.it</a> oppure chiedi aiuto <a href="http://www.dday.it/contact">all'antennista</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'Montserrat';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    src: local('Montserrat-Bold'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/montserrat/v3/IQHow_FEYlDC4Gzy_m8fcgFhaRv2pGgT5Kf0An0s4MM.woff) format('woff');
}
body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, li, dl, dt, dd, img, form, fieldset, input, textarea, blockquote {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
body {
    background-color: #000;
    background-image: url(http://media.dday.it/roby/404/404_files/images/static.gif);
    font-family:'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
body, html, div {
    height: 100%;
}
#tv {
    background-image: url(http://media.dday.it/roby/404/404_files/images/tv.png), url(http://media.dday.it/roby/404/404_files/images/shading.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
#content {
    width: 60%;
    height: 65%;
    position: relative;
    top: 20%;
    left: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}
#logo {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto 2em auto;
}
#logo img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
h1 {
    font-family: Serif;
    font-size: 10em;
    margin: 0 0 0.1em 0;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 3em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    margin: 0 0 1.3em 0;
}
h2 span {
    font-size: 2.05em;
    display: block;
}
p {
    font-size: 2em;
}
a {
    color: #4be300;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: #4be300;
}
```

Comment: Bella pagina :) You should make a fiddle with that and post the code too by editing your answer or this will be closed really soon :/

Comment: @AndreaLigios l'ho fatto: http://jsfiddle.net/LAKXK/ ma non me lo fa inserire e non capisco perchè!

Comment: Now that we have progressed past english - should I post my answer in Italian?

Comment: Oh sorry, you are right! :)

Comment: It depends if you are looking for upvotes or downvotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, :)

You may use mediaqueires to set font-size:
http://jsfiddle.net/LAKXK/3/

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'Montserrat';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    src: local('Montserrat-Bold'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/montserrat/v3/IQHow_FEYlDC4Gzy_m8fcgFhaRv2pGgT5Kf0An0s4MM.woff) format('woff');
}
body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, li, dl, dt, dd, img, form, fieldset, input, textarea, blockquote {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
body {
    background-color: #000;
    background-image: url(http://media.dday.it/roby/404/404_files/images/static.gif);
    font-family:'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
body, html, div {
    height: 100%;
}
#tv {
    background-image: url(http://media.dday.it/roby/404/404_files/images/tv.png), url(http://media.dday.it/roby/404/404_files/images/shading.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
#content {
    width: 60%;
    height: 65%;
    position: relative;
    top: 20%;
    left: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}
#logo {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto 2em auto;
}
#logo img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
h1 {
    font-family: Serif;
    font-size: 10em;
    margin: 0 0 0.1em 0;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 3em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    margin: 0 0 1.3em 0;
}
h2 span {
    font-size: 2.05em;
    display: block;
}
p {
    font-size: 2em;
}
a {
    color: #4be300;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: #4be300;
}
@media all and (max-width:2700px) {html {font-size:16px;transition:1s;}}
@media all and (max-width:2000px) {html {font-size:14px;transition:1s;}}
@media all and (max-width:1600px) {html {font-size:13px;transition:1s;}}
@media all and (max-width:1200px) {html {font-size:12px;transition:1s;}}
@media all and (max-width:1100px) {html {font-size:11px;transition:1s;}}
@media all and (max-width: 900px) {html {font-size:10px;transition:1s;}}
@media all and (max-width: 700px) {html {font-size:9px;transition:1s;}}
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {html {font-size:8px;transition:1s;}}
@media all and (max-width: 300px) {html {font-size: 6px;transition:1s;}}
```

And use em in your online style (you should move this to CSS file )

```
<script src="./404_files/jquery.fittext.js"></script>
<script src="./404_files/scripts.js"></script>
<div id="tv">
    <div id="content"> <a href="http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/" id="logo"><img src="http://media.dday.it/roby/404/404_files/images/ddaylog.png" alt="DDay Logo"/></a> 
            <h1 class="scale1" style="font-size: 3em;">404</h1>

            <h2 class="scale2" style="font-size: 3em;"><span>Non c'è nulla</span> su questa frequenza</h2>

        <p class="scale3" style="font-size: 3em;">Cambia canale e torna su <a href="http://www.dday.it/">DDay.it</a> oppure chiedi aiuto <a href="http://www.dday.it/contact">all'antennista</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Bella pagina

Comment: Thank you

My goal is not only to resize font, but to obtain a page with a white background and my TV positionet in the center that can scale in differente devices without losing proportion (the TV is 4:3).

Comment: you need background-size:contain; and no-repeat.+ media queries. Better, keep image in html , set text-over it and size it with mediaqueries.